# MVC3 - Communicating between the template and the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I’m using MVC3 (with Razor Syntax).

Here’s what I’m going for: part of my `shared/_Layout.cshtml` which looks in the ViewBag for a `List<RelatedLinks>`, if it’s there it renders a list of related links in the page toolbar (unsurprisingly). Some of my pages will populate this collection, some wont. When I populate the bag from my controller it works beautifully.

However, the controller doesn't seem like the right place for these to be defined, they’re specific to a view and they feel like navigation logic – so I’d like to define them within the view markup.

I've tried adding them to the `ViewBag` from within the view, but it doesn’t seem to work. Even if I declare a section on my `_Layout.cshtml` that comes before the area which renders the links, the collection appears to be empty. Either I’m doing something wrong, or they don’t allow me to fill the `ViewBag` from within the view (which would make sense).

What my problem boils down to is this: I want my pages to signal to the `_Layout.cshtml` when they want that section rendered, and provide the list of links. I don’t want my child pages to worry about how we’re populating or drawing the list – I only want it to define what’s in the list. Any ideas? I've tried quite a few things (HtmlHelpers, sub-classing controller, etc) but I think I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having `_Layout.cshtml` render the links, why not create a partial view instead?

In _Layout, add an optional section

```
@RenderSection("RelatedLinks", false)
```

In your view,

```
// Build your list of links
@section RelatedLinks {
    @Html.Partial("Navigation", YourLinks)
}
```

Your views can worry about populating the list, while your partial can handle the actual rendering.

Comment: This seems like a good thought. I like that the logic for building it all is in one place, but I'd rather that one place be within the `_Layout.cshtml page` (I'm reusing this layout page in a few other places, and it'd be cumbersome to bring those partial views with it).

Comment: Not sure what you mean, there's only one partial view, "Navigation" that would be in `~/Views/Shared` and that would handle transform its model (list of links) into the HTML you need. Each view, e.g. `~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` would use the code above and actually *provide* the links model to the partial. Alternatively, the `_Layout.cshtml` file can provide that model (if you don't do it per-view). If that's the case, I'd switch to using `@{Html.RenderAction("Home", "RelatedLinks");}` instead.

Comment: What I mean is that I'm reusing that `_Layout.cshtml` in some other websites, and I'd like for that render logic to be encapsulated within that page. Otherwise, I have to include that partial view in the other sites as well. Not a deal-breaker, but not ideal either. Inside my "Related Links" section, it's using `Html.RenderAction` and rendering links for external pages.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work fine:

_Layout.cshtml:

```
if(IsSectionDefined("Links")){
    @RenderSection("Links");

    @foreach(var link in ViewBag.Links)
    {
        <a href="@link.href">@link.text</a>
    }
}
```

MyView.cshtml:

```
@section Links{
    @{
        ViewBag.Links = new List { new {href="stackoverflow.com", text = "Stackoverflow"}};
    }

}
```

Comment: You're doing what I described above (I already tried it) by adding to the ViewBag from within the view. That doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

You make a good point that if a list of related links is specific to a view, it deserves to be treated as navigation logic as opposed to application logic. "Hard coding" the list of links in the view seems like the right approach.

Still, you definitely want to separate the logic that *renders* the list of links from the list of links itself (the *data*). A partial view should work well for this. Just define a partial that accepts a list of related links (perhaps in the form of a page title plus a raw URL, or a route, or whatever works for you).

On each view where you want to display a list of related links, define a list and pass it to the partial for rendering:

### 1. MyView.cshtml

```
@{
    var relatedLinks = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
        { "Link one", "/foo" },
        { "Link two", "/foo" }
    };
}
@Html.Partial("RelatedLinks", relatedLinks)
```

### 1. RelatedLinks.cshtml

```
<ul>
@foreach(var link in model) {
    <li>@Html.Link(model.Key, model.Value)</li>
}
</ul>
```

You can place all this within a `@Section`, and tell `_Layout.cs` to only render the "related links" section on the page if you have actually defined such a section in your view.

### 2. MyView.cshtml

```
@Section Links {
    @{
        var relatedLinks = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
            { "Link one", "/foo" },
            { "Link two", "/foo" }
        };
    }
    @Html.Partial("RelatedLinks", relatedLinks)
}
```

### 2. _Layout.cshtml

```
@RenderSection("Links", required: false); // Optional section
```

Comment: A good idea, but it's pretty much the same as Brandon's answer.